# curl command not working from within shell script but works fine out site

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sh

I am struggling with a small bash shell script that should list my csv files and upload them to a external Service using curl. 
when i echo my command variable out to console and execute it i works fine, 
but when i execute it within my script it complains about a extra qouta "

my script looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
LOGDIR="/var/log/tyk/"
FILE_EXSTENSION_NAME="*.csv"
CURLCMD="curl -k -i -H"
PORT="9992"
ENDPOINT="/endpoint"
URL="https://localhost"



for i in `ls $LOGDIR$FILE_EXSTENSION_NAME`; do
    filename=`echo $i | awk -F "/" ' { print $5 }'`
    echo $filename
    CMD="$CURLCMD \"filename: $filename\" -F \"data=@$LOGDIR$filename\" $URL:$PORT$ENDPOINT"
    $CMD
done
```

When i run it i getfollowing output

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time     Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 2018-October-18-10.csv"; Unknown error
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--      0     
curl: (26) couldn't open file "/var/log/tyk/2018-October-18-10.csv""
```

If i do a echo $CMD in my script i got

```
curl -k -i -H "filename: 2018-October-18-10.csv" -F "data=@/var/log/tyk/2018-October-18-10.csv" https://localhost:9992/endpoint
```

and that works ok

I cannot figure out what it is that i am not doing wrong

Comment: `URL="https:localhost"` - is that a typo? What is the exact error messasge you get? You show a `curl` error message that it can't open a file, but you talk about "missing quote" errors from `bash`. What is it?

Comment: yes it is URL=https://localhost" its because i changed it so i didnt expose the real URL. The errors is curl: (26) couldn't open file "/var/log/tyk/2018-October-18-10.csv"" there are two quotas in the end of the string but in my script i only set one. The file exists -rw-r--r--. 1 tyk tyk 1250 Oct 18 10:17 /var/log/tyk/2018-October-18-10.csv

Comment: Please edit your original question to correct the `URL=` part and also tell us the exact error message you get. Maybe instead of invoking `awk`, you want to use the `basename` tool to get the filename? Also, use `ls -1` or better `find` to get at the list of filenames. And output `$CMD` before running it so you see what actually gets run.

Comment: there error is curl: (26) couldn't open file "/var/log/tyk/2018-October-18-10.csv""

Comment: Don't put the command in a variable, just execute it directly (see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, don't store commands in variables.
Apart from that, there are two problems:

1. Quotes inside expanded variables do not work as if you typed them in directly.
2. The subshell `$()` around `$($CMD)` seems suspicous. Not only do you execute the command stored in `$CMD`, but you also execute the output of that command!

#### 1. Quotes inside variables

When you enter the command `echo "a   b"` then `bash` will process that command such that `echo` is executed with the argument `a   b`. The output will be `a   b`.

When you store that command inside a variable and expand that variable, `bash` will process the variable's content differently. The command `echo` will be executed with the arguments `"a` and `b"`. The output will be `"a b"`.

This is the reason for the error message

> `curl: (26) couldn't open file "/var/log/tyk/2018-October-18-10.csv""`

`curl` is trying to open a path with an actual quote inside. Such a path does not exist on your system.

To get around this issue, you *could* write `eval "$cmd"`, then the command would be executed as if you typed it in directly. However, you really shouldn't. I'd rewrite the script instead to *not* store commands in variables.

#### 2. Subshell around `$cmd`:

```
cmd='echo something'
$cmd
```

This would print `something`.
However, your script doesn't stop there, because you enclosed `$cmd` in `$()`. Therefore the output `something` gets executed too.

```
cmd='echo something'
$($cmd)
```

results in

```
bash: something: command not found
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i still gets the same result if i change $($CMD) to $CMD but if echo out my $CMD and run it manually it works fine

Comment: @havmaage The real reason was a bit hidden in my answer. I tried to make it more clear be reworking my answer.

Comment: Oh figured it out didn't read your explanation properly at the first time , ofcourse echo "a b" it makes sense changed my command to **curl -k -i -H "filename: $filename" -F "data=@$LOGDIR$filename"  $URL:$PORT$ENDPOINT** and now it works thank you very much